# Removing 01/01/1 dates in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

For null dates returned from server the jqgrid is showing as 01/01/1. How I can remove the dates on showing them in the grid at all?

Vijaya Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use predefined date formatter (`formatter:'date'`) the problem which you describe not exist.

[The small demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocaWithUndefinedDate.htm) shows that undefined filed with dates, empty strings and `null` values will be  displayed as empty cells and not as "01/01/1".

Comment: I specified that property and I think the problem is not in jqgrid side, the ASP.NET MVC web app is returning empty date as 01/01/1 so the serialized json has negative values for ex. "ModifiedDate": "\/Date(-62135596800000+0530)\/". Do I want to fix this problem in server side or I can solve this problem some-how in jqgrid side?

Comment: I solved the problem by using nullable datetime fileds in server-side. Thanks for your reply.